# Posting to both Delicious and Pinboard at the same time with a bookmarklet

Tags: delicious, bookmarklet, pinboard

I'm trying to cross post between Delicious and Pinboard with a bookmarklet but don't know how to create it.

I want to be able to keep the tags and notes intact. I know that Pinboard will sync with delicious (every few hours) but I'd prefer to have one bookmarklet that posts to both sites at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Merry Christmas, I just made you this Bookmarklet that does both:

```
javascript:q=location.href;if(document.getSelection){d=document.getSelection();}else{d='';};p=document.title;void(open('http://pinboard.in/add?next=http://www.delicious.com/save?url='+encodeURIComponent(q)+'&description='+encodeURIComponent(d)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(p)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(q)+'&description='+encodeURIComponent(d)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(p),'Pinboard', 'toolbar=no,width=700,height=350'));
```

Technically it doesnt add them at the same time, it does one after the other.  It takes advantage of Pinboard.in's `next=` url parameter that I added to the regular bookmarklet.  In it I specified it to go immediately to the delicious add url.

So, when you click on it, **it will bring up the popup window for you to add the bookmark to Pinboard and as soon as you hit save, the popup window changes to a delicious popup window where you can save it there as well.**

It will populate the url and title automatically, but since this is happening before you enter your tags and note, they are not passed on and you'll have to type them in again.

Comment: thanks - that's smart.  Ideally would love a way to have it post to both and maintain the notes & tags, instead of having to enter them twice.

Comment: There may be a way to tweak it but its a little outside my skill set. Also, you should email the pinboard dev, he's very responsive to user input.

Answer (score 1):

If I want them posted to both, I can post to delicious and configure pinboard to pull from delicious RSS feed (http://pinboard.in/settings/).  There are limitations to this path, as well, but ... it works.

Comment: Thanks - I eluded to that in my original question though :)

Comment: FYI, my actual solution now is If This Then That --> https://ifttt.com/recipes/15008 for this particular task. I get better control over content that is sent to delicious.

Comment: Thanks - I've been using ifttt to accomplish the same thing for quite some time now. Not the bookmarklet solution I was originally looking for but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iMacros macro for that. These are little macros for your web browser. To run them, use the free/open source iMacros for Firefox or iMacros for IE addons

http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Bookmarking